# jdbc не работают тесты подключения к базе даных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, jdbc, junit

Есть два класса один тестирует подключение к базе данных, другой внесение записей в базу данных и чтение из неё. В каждом классе есть такой код:

```
static Connection connection;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {

        connection = DBconnector.getInstance().getConnection();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void close() throws SQLException {
        connection.close();


    }
```

Если запустить по отдельности эти тесты то они работают нормально, если же вместе то вываливает SQL исключение `No operations allowed after connection closed.`

По моему происходит какой то лаг когда после закрытия соединения не получается сразу же открыть его еще раз. Можно было бы обьеденить эти два класса в один тест, но как я читал это будет плохим тоном, каждый класс должен иметь свой тест.

Comment: Покажите код класса `DBconnector`, подозреваю, проблема в нём.

Comment: ссылка на пастебин http://pastebin.com/dbvThF4C

Comment: К слову о бесполезности синглтонов

Comment: Почему вы решили, что "подключение к базе должно быть одно"?

Comment: Где то читал или смотрел видеоурок с каким то умным дядей, он так говорил

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь, но настоящие специалисты не делают видеоуроков. На конференциях выступают, статьи/книги пишут, но не видеоуроки. Вы больше того дядю не слушайте.

Comment: И если это не домашнее задание по работе с соединениями, советую сразу использовать какой-нибудь пул, типа https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `DBconnector` должен при каждом вызове `getConnection()` открывать новое соединение к БД и возвращать его. А у вас он всегда возвращает одно и то же соединение. Поэтому, когда в одном тесте оно закрывается (`connection.close()`
), в другом тесте его уже не получается использовать.